# Erro ao rodar dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

**Possuo** um `dockerfile` que roda uma aplicação em **node.js**

```
FROM node

RUN npm install mongoose

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app &&\
  npm install --global npm@3.7.5

ENV HOME=/home/app

COPY package.json $HOME/library/
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*

USER app
WORKDIR $HOME/library
RUN npm install --silent --progress=false

USER root
COPY . $HOME/library
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*
USER app

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

e um `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    command: "mongod"
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
  library:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec npm start
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/library
      - /home/app/library/node_modules
    links:
      - db
```

Depois executar `docker-compose build` tento rodar com `docker-compose up`

Então o erro acontece:

```
    > node-rest-auth@ start /home/app/library
> node server.js

/home/app/library/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^

Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/app/library/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:689:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at bindings (/home/app/library/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/library/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/library/app/models/user.js:3:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-rest-auth@ start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-rest-auth@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-05T16_21_54_845Z-debug.log
```

Comment: @BrunoCésar O erro continua. Eu consegui consertar o erro, irei postar aqui como consegui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após muito tentar conseguir consertar o tal erro

O **erro** na verdade é bastante simples. Ao fazer o `COPY . $HOME/library` e rodar o `docker build .` nós **enviamos** o `node_modules` *junto*. Isso faz com que as **configurações** do `npm install` *são* na verdade o da **máquina pessoal**.

Existe uma maneira simples de resolvermos isso que é **criando** (ou adicionando o `node_modules` caso já tenha tal arquivo) um `.dockerignore` onde iremos **colocar** o `node_modules`, ficando assim:

**.dockerignore**

```
node_modules
```

Com isso devemos consertar o problema.

**Limpe** os caches, ou **exclua** todas as imagens(que foi o que eu fiz), e então execute o `docker build .` ou `docker-compose build` novamente, e o erro não estará mais lá.